# Delete one character at a time from an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sending a value to an HTML div as a user types, collectively that makes a string I need to use in the #finalkey div. I currently have an option to clear the value, but I'm wondering how I could allow for deleting one character of the HTML at a time like a backspace.

```
 // When someone clicks the key send the html value to another div
 // Display keys as user types
 $( ".key" ).on( "click", function() {
  var thekeyvalue = $(this).html();
  $('#finalkey').append(document.createTextNode(thekeyvalue));
 });

 //When someone clicks clear clear the value
 // Clear keys when user clicks clear
 $( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
   $('#finalkey').empty();
 });
```

Comment: you can use slice on the string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: If you are sending the value of the input to the div as they type, wouldn't hitting backspace in the input also make the div reflect the backspaced change?  Or really any change to the input field?  It's kinda unclear how a user typing on a keyboard relates to this .key binding on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're mixing jQuery syntax with vanilla JavaScript. If you're using jQuery in your project, you can do all your stuff with it (just a suggestion).

So, one approach is to create a new **letter** adding a new `<span>` element, like this:

```
var newLetter = $("<span></span>", {
   text: $(this).html()
});
```

This will allow you to customize it (you can set a class `letter`, for instance).

So, to remove the last `span` of `#finalkey` element, you can use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to retrieve all childrens, and select last one with [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) and remove it with [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
   $('#finalkey').children().last().remove();
});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/L1mmhbu0/

A "fancy" version: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/L1mmhbu0/6/

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```js
$( ".key" ).on( "click", function() {
  var thekeyvalue = 'keyvaluetext';
  $('#finalkey').append(document.createTextNode(thekeyvalue));
 });

 
 $( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
   $('#finalkey').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(0, -1);
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="finalkey"></div>

<button class="key">Add text</div>
<button class="delete">Remove last char</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great option!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read the content, remove the last character and assign it again?

```
var text=$('#finalkey').text();
$('#finalkey').text(text.substring(0,text.length-1));
```

Also, I think `document.createTextNode` is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this ..

```
$( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
   var a = $('#finalkey').text();
       a = a.substr(0, a.length - 1);
       $('#finalkey').html(a);
 });
```